# gog.com's login link missing only in Firefox (for HTTP)

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, html

gog.com has a HTTP site (http://www.gog.com/) and a HTTPS site (https://secure.gog.com/).

When I visit the HTTPS site in Firefox, the *Login/Sign-up* link is visible:

[image: gog.com via HTTPS on Firefox]

When I visit the HTTP site in Firefox, the link is **missing**:

[image: gog.com via HTTP on Firefox]

But when I visit the HTTP site in Chromium, the link is visible:

[image: gog.com via HTTP on Chromium]

So gog.com doesn't seem to hide the login link in general on HTTP. In fact, if I disable the CSS, I can see the login form on the HTTP variant on Firefox, too:

[image: gog.com via HTTP on Firefox without CSS]

I contacted the gog.com support, but they were not able to reproduce it.

I tested it with three different Firefox installations on different systems, and I never saw the *Login/Sign-up* via HTTP. Is it only me?!

I checked the source code with Firebug. For HTTP, the relevant part seems to be:

```
<div class="nav_user">
  <div class="nav_empty not_logged"></div>
</div>
```

For HTTPS, it looks like:

```
<div class="nav_user">
  <div class="nav_link nav_account nav_login" data-hoverclass="hover_acc">
    <span class="nav_login_icon"></span>
    <span class="nav_text">Login / Sign-up</span>
    <div class="nav_hover"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav_cart_h">
    <div class="nav_empty"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does someone have an explanation for this? Why does it work in other browsers but not in Firefox?

**EDIT**: Other things on their HTTP site don't seem to work in Firefox either (but on HTTPS without any problems). For example I can't use the big carousel on the home page: clicking the navigation arrows doesn't do anything, clicking at one game neither.

So all these problems are probably related to JavaScript? Does Firefox have any security features that disallow some functions on HTTPS or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, *gog.com* requires local storage for HTTP (but not HTTPS).

So the about:config setting [`dom.storage.enabled`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dom.storage.enabled) needs to be `true`.

(Similar [problem](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/699/1361) with JS on anime.stackexchange.com and japanese.stackexchange.com)